# Gas Fireplace Turns off after heating up

Tags: gas, fireplace, propane

I have a propane ventless gas log. It's a Rasmussen Chillbuster C1B. It has worked fine for 15 years.

Now when I turn it on it burns for about 15 minutes and then cuts off. The pilot is still light and there is no smell of gas.

Anyone know what I should be checking?

Comment: Does it have a thermostat? Can you locate the thermal protection switches?

Comment: It does not have a thermostat.
I'm afraid I don't know how to identify it. Is that the same as a thermocouple?

Comment: Possibly. The point is that you may have one that's gotten tired. Without model information it's difficult to provide specific advice.

Comment: http://rasmussen.host4kb.com/getAttach/478/AA-01133/C1.DFC1.203.pdf might help. Specifically, "Obstructed Pilot Air Intake Ports result in an improper gas/air mixture and a weak pilot flame. Weak pilot flame
is the NUMBER 1 SERVICE ISSUE RE NUISANCE SHUT-OFF. Using canned compressed air , pipe
cleaner or an artist's brush, clean out the opposing Air Intake Ports located at base of Pilot (where gas supply line
attaches to pilot)"